# display a pre-loader in Angular before it load first component

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using **Angular 6**.

My application takes a few seconds before it loads the component and that time is spent in loading resources and validating the user.

While all this happens, my application displays a blank white page.

I want to replace that ugly white page with a **preloader** that will be displayed until all background process is complete.

For that I have added a CSS loading spinner inside the `index.html` like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <!-- Fonts and icons -->

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <!-- Pre-loading spinner -->
    <!-- This code within the app-root will be wiped of once the child component is loaded -->
    <!-- This code will not even be shown in the source code once the child component is loaded -->
    <!-- We can put any code css/html/image/etc here -->

    <style>
      /** CSS here. Since it will be wiped totally, 'll not cause any impact to the core stylesheet.
    </style>

    Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And this displays a page like

[image]

But the issue is that. The first loaded component is **app.component.html** which has following content

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Which further loads another component **admin-layout-component.html** with contents

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar" data-color="red">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div class="main-panel">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

As soon as **app.component** is loaded, the spinner content from **index.html** is removed and start displaying the blank page until **admin-layout** is loaded.

I tried adding same styling code inside the **router-outlet** of **app.component.html** but then when the component is loaded, the contents are added along with the spinner and spinner is not removed from other pages.

**How can I display the spinner on `app.component.html` as well until dashboard page is loaded.**

Here is a video how it is working: https://youtu.be/RSlTi0EQHm4

Answer (score 17):

I got this working in Angular 8, based on Sunil's answer. I'm hiding the loader element from the App Component, which is initialized before any other component. So no need to add this everywhere.

Manipulating the DOM using [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) is not recommended so I'm using [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) instead.

index.html:

```html
<body class="theme-primary">
  <div id="loader">
    <style>
      .application-loading-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .application-loading-box {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="application-loading-container">
      <div class="application-loading-box"><h2>Loading...</h2></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let loader = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#loader');
    this.renderer.setStyle(loader, 'display', 'none');
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your statement about using Renderer and not directly manipulating DOM, you should probably change: `loader.style.display = "none";` to `this.renderer.setStyle(loader, 'display', 'none');`

Comment: The statement was regarding the use of ElementRef to manipulate the DOM. But your suggestion is probably the preferred way of doing it. I'll update my post.

Comment: Your answer did helpful for me, now all work, thank !

Answer (score 9):

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'body[osk-root]',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent{/* Not need remove element or change style*/}
```

index.html

```
<body osk-root><!--YOUR LOADER--></body>
```

after appcomponent succefully loaded , angular clears `innerHtml` of `body[osk-root]` element

Comment: This one is perfect since this does not depend on angular being loaded and shows instantly, I've included the styles within the <app-root> so it resets styles on start, works like charm!


To test out here copy HTML from this and put it inside the <app-root> inside your index.html and you should have a fully functional pre-loading screen https://codepen.io/Cruelplatypus67/pen/rNLVggQ

Comment: Man, its perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

First of all your implementation is pretty standard way to show the loading spinner.

### Issue

The issue is not with the app component. Spinner is disappearing after the app component is loaded. The blank page you are seeing because of Dashboard Component which is huge in size and it could have multiple API calls. So basically spinner is working as expected. Issue is with Dashboard Component

### Fix

1.If you want to fix then you need hide handle spinner in the Dashboard Component.
Create the a  and put your spinner content in it instead of `<app-root>`

```
<body>
  <div id="loader">
     <!-- Pre-loading spinner -->
    <!-- This code within the app-root will be wiped of once the child component is loaded -->
    <!-- This code will not even be shown in the source code once the child component is loaded -->
    <!-- We can put any code css/html/image/etc here -->

    <style>
      /** CSS here. Since it will be wiped totally, 'll not cause any impact to the core stylesheet.
    </style>

    Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
  </div>

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

#### Dashboard Component

Hide the div with id loader in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
@Component({selector: 'dashbaord', template: `...`})
class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     let loader = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#loader'); 
     loader.style.display = "none"; //hide loader
  }
}
```

Comment: This way I need to add `ngAfterViewInit` to all the components. because when visiting another component from URL directly like `www.example.com/contacts` then also it will have the blank screen just like that of `dashboard`?

Comment: Also it is not working as expected because Inline CSS is effecting CSS of the main application. I want to remove the CSS and all spinner content once main component is loaded.

Comment: Instead of hiding the `div`, remove the content of div `this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: This will solve my 2nd query but what about first. Do I need to add `ngAfterViewInit` to all the components? So that when visited any component directly, it will work as expected?

Comment: First problem will not be happening. First component will disappear once the next component or page appears. If you still have some issue than you should implement the spinner as most of the site does.

Comment: This is a horrible solution. I'm not going to add this to every component, tell me angular figured out a better way...